# Fullwave rectifier with active clamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier, inverting-amplifier, precision-rectifier

What is wrong with my simulation? I am simulating with LTspice the following circuit taken from "Art of Electronics 3ed"[image: fullwave_rectifier_with_clamp]

where my LTspice model looks as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong as there can be seen some glitches at the output? My feeling tells me that it has something to do with the slew-rate of the opamps but the experts here can probably tell me more.

The simulation uses the **UniversalOpAmp** model from the default LTspice library.

**EDIT**

After changing the opamp model to UniversalOpAmp2 the following result at the output was obtained:

[image: fullwave_rectifier_with_universal_opamp2]

And with a more detailed look by comparing the output signal against the comparator output:

[image: vcomp_out_vs_vout]

From what I can see by looking at the comparator output that there are still some glitches, probably caused by the propagation delay until the closed-loop clamping circuit reaches steady-state. Is this something that we have to live with or are there ways to minimize this further?

Comment: What opamp model are you using?

Comment: It's the UniversalOpAmp model from the default LTspice library.

Comment: You need to used UniversalOpamp2

Comment: Yes, that helped. Many thx!

Comment: Look at the voltage output of U4.

Comment: So the simulation works and this solves all the problems? Now we expect you to share what you saw and what you understood from it... Otherwise the benefit of it is negligible...

Answer (score 1):

Note that output is not "regular" ... Made with TLC2272.

See the "difference" in amplitude.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change X2 to LM358?

Comment: @G36 Tried with LM358 ... Perfect at 50 Hz !

Answer (score 1):

IC2 operates in two regimes. In one, its output is saturated to the negative rail (0V in this case), and the diode is reverse biased. The diode effectively disconnects IC2 from the rest of the circuit.

The second regime is where the diode is forward biased, with about 0.6V across it, and the non-inverting input of IC1 is clamped at exactly 0V.

The glitches occur during the transition between these two conditions, a moment when the output of IC2 (U4 in your schematic) is required to jump in potential by at least 0.6V. It can't do that instantly, due to limited slew rate, and so there's a short period when IC2's output "races" to catch up, to suddenly jump by 0.6V (or more), to forward bias the diode again.

The reason the authors chose to power IC2 from ground (0V) instead of some negative potential, is to prevent its output from going significantly negative, when the diode is supposed to be reverse biased. This keeps the size of the "potential jump" of its output required to bring the diode into forward bias to a minimum, a single diode-drop of 0.6V, instead of having to slew upwards by many volts, which would take much longer.

I recommend that you actually power U4/IC2 from a negative supply, and watch its output to see how it takes much longer to "recover" from negative saturation, and worsens the glitches you are are witnessing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSMm1z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Below I plot \$V_{IN}\$ (blue), \$V_{OUT}\$ (orange) and \$V_X\$, IC2's output (tan):

[image]

The left-hand green marker shows when the input becomes negative, and where ideally you would want IC1's output to start rising again. It doesn't though. That's because prior to this point, IC2's output is heavily saturated against its own negative supply rail, -15V.

Between the vertical green markers, you see IC2's output "race" upwards as fast as it can, from -15V all the way up to +0.6V, pretty linearly because it's limited by its slew rate, which in this case seems to be about 15V in 5μs, or 3V/μs.

Eventually it reaches +0.6V, which forward biases D1, just prior to the right-hand green marker. IC1 is also slew-rate limited, and also has to "catch up", which finally occurs at the right-hand marker, at 55.7μs.

The result is that the output of IC1 continues to follow the input even after it's gone negative, for way longer than we would like, causing a "glitch".

To minimise the time it takes for X to rise to +0.6V, we prevent the op-amp's output from going so far negative in the first place, by supplying the op-amp with 0V instead of -15V. It still has to make the jump from 0V to +0.6V, which will still take some time, but not nearly so long. You'll still get a "glitch", but it will be much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Since things went backwards, back to front, let's end with what we had to start with - the idea, the intuitive explanation, the implementation...

## Basic rectifier idea

The idea of ​​a full-wave rectifier is simple - one (for example, the positive) half-wave is passed without change and the other (negative) is reversed (inverted).

## Diode rectifier

In the simple diode bridge circuit, this is done by diode switches which reverse the current direction of one of the half-waves.

## Op-amp rectifier

The idea behind this op-amp circuit is for a (single) diode to control an op-amp amplifier (IC 1) so that it operates as a *follower* during the positive half-wave and as an *inverter* during the negative half-wave. Switching is done by grounding the point X (inverter) or leaving it ungrounded (follower).

For simplicity, let's first replace the diode with a mechanical SPST switch SW and apply a 1 V DC input voltage. The trick here is that the input voltage is applied through a resistor R3 to the non-inverting input. In this way, the source internal resistance is intentionally increased and can be controlled by shunting.

### SW = ON: Inverting amplifier

This is simply an inverting amplifier with a gain of -R2/R1 = -1 with grounded non-inverting input (the resistor R3 does not play any role, it only loads the input source a bit). So the output voltage is -1 V.

### SW = OFF: Non-inverting amplifier

Here we can see two more clever tricks. First, the input voltage is completely passed through R3 due to the high input resistance of the non-inverting input (no voltage drop across R3). Figuratively speaking, the current through R3 is stopped by the extremely high op-amp input resistance.

The op-amp must supply the same voltage to its inverting input through the negative feedback circuit. This means that no current should flow through R1. Another piece of wisdom is that current can be stopped not only through resistance but also through opposite voltage. This is what the op-amp does by making its output voltage equal to the input voltage - no current flows through the R1-R2 network. So the output voltage is 1 V (and not only the output voltage but all potentials along the R1-R2 network).

### "Ideal" diode

Unfortunately, the diode is not an "ideal" switch with zero forward voltage drop VF, but we can make it so with the help of another op-amp (IC 2). It adds the same voltage VF in series that compensates for the diode VF when forward-biased (at Vin = -1 V).

When it is reverse biased, the op-amp remains without feedback and its output voltage reaches the negative supply rail, which is not good for fast operation. That is why the op-amp is single-supplied.

### Completed circuit

Now all that remains is to replace the mechanical switch with the "ideal" diode one...